# How to fix cocoapods trunk cdn issue?

Tags: react-native, installation

I am trying to setup a react-native app from scratch.
During install, I get the following error

Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/sachinchandorkar/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

I have tried installing the pod manually without success

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and there was a cdn issue with cocoapods so visit.
https://status.cocoapods.org/# and see if everything is working alright first

Answer (score 0):

This helped..
In terminal execute command `chflags -R nouchg .`

Comment: in what directory?

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check if the XCode CLI is selected properly.

Xcode --> Preferences --> Locations --> Command Line Tools:

[image]

Then run pod install or pod update

Comment: This did not work for me. Even after updating OS to Catalina.